# How to open exact activity/screen from my android app like through ADB

Tags: java, android

I want to add button in my application to open Connections screen in Android Settings.

It's working through ADB via command:

```
adb shell am start -a com.android.settings.action.SETTINGS -n com.android.settings/.Settings\$\ConnectionsSettingsActivity
```

But I have no idea how to implement it into my app... I tried by:

```
Intent launchIntent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.android.settings");
if (launchIntent != null) {
   startActivity(launchIntent);
}
```

but it open of course main screen of settings. I tried also various combinations of

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("package.name", "activity.name"));
startActivity(intent);
```

How to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
intent.setClassName("com.android.phone", "com.android.phone.NetworkSetting");
startActivity(intent);
```

Replace `NetworkSetting` with `Settings` for `DATA_ROAMING_SETTINGS`.

Also you can try this as well:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
        intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.android.settings",
                "com.android.settings.Settings$DataUsageSummaryActivity"));
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        startActivity(intent);
```

### Edit

This is how the question author solved it:

```
   Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.android.settings", "com.android.settings.Settings$ConnectionsSettingsActivity"));
    startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 2):

OK I checked setting window with:

```
adb shell dumpsys window windows | grep 'mCurrentFocus'
```

and got:

```
  mCurrentFocus=Window{c155a84 u0 com.android.example/com.android.settings.example}
```

and it's working with:

```
        Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.android.settings", "com.android.settings.Settings$ConnectionsSettingsActivity"));
    startActivity(intent);
```

Thanks!! :D

Comment: I use `adb shell dumpsys window windows | grep -E 'mCurrentFocus|mFocusedApp|mObscuringWindow'` as on Huawei's Harmony OS, the "mObscuringWindow'" points to the currently open Activity.